# Convergence of an Iterative Sequence...

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $g(x)=\frac{2+x}{1+x}$. Set now the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ such that $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$. Show that this sequence converges and, furthermore, converges to $\sqrt[]{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1: Show that this sequence converges.

Part 2: If it converges to a limit $L$, then $L=g(L)=\frac{2+L}{1+L}$.  Rearrange to $L+L^2=2+L$, which has solutions $\pm \sqrt{2}$.

Part 3: Show that it doesn't converge to $-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: And, @vadim123, how do I show that it converges? Some hint? It is a Cauchy sequence, isn't?

Comment: Show that it is bounded and monotonous. This implies convergence.